# uBootstrap for Umbraco

Tags: responsive-design, umbraco

I have a legacy Umbraco site which I need to make responsive. I decided to use uBootstrap for this. I downloaded the files, but I cannot find any documentation on how to integrate this with my current site. Is there something I need to install? There's no installer file.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation here, presumably where you downloaded it from:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/ubootstrap

It is a starter kit, so you will probably only really be able to use it when you are creating a brand new site.

Packages listed at http://our.umbraco.org will always have a "Package discussions" link at the bottom for reading or raising questions just like this.